# Displaying subscripted variables in GUIKit

Tags: gui-construction, subscript

I'm trying to build a custom interface using Mathematica and I want to write something inside a textfield with a subscript, however, when I run the GUI, I see boxes on the places where there should be the subscripted text, for exemple: if I do "text"$\rightarrow$"$R_1$", I get things like this:

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using GUIKit? This is already deprecated.

Comment: The only text strings you can use in GUIKit are strings that Java can accept. Therefore, Mathematica `Subscript` calls can not be used. This may  be one of the reasons GUIKit has been abandoned.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that! Is there any other way of doing graphic interfaces like the one I showed before, with mathematica?

Comment: Btw, the purpose is to calculate electrical resistances by solving eight non linear equations using FindRoot, after measuring the equivalent resistances in two wheatstones bridges. Should I move to another software, like matlab and build the interface there? (if possible i would love to continue to use mathematica)

Comment: @RicardoP take a look at `CreateDialog`, `InputField` and in general `guide/CustomInterfaceConstruction`

Comment: This looks doable with `Manipulate[]` and a little bit of programming effort. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 11.1.1. I thought that manipulate was used for dynamic plotting